# Problem with command button inside panel

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a code that when I choose an option from my selectOneMenu generate a panel contain Inputtext and commandButton .The problem that the commandButton don't work inside the panel
when I perss the button the page just reload (I have a 3 button one  generate a PDF report,the second navigate to another page and the third for Reset),I have add one button for know just for test.
My code JSF ChooseKPI.xhtml:

```
      <h:form>

         <br></br>
         KPIs:<h:selectOneMenu  style="width:200px" immediate="true"  value="#{ToolsKPI.myChoice}" onchange="submit()"  valueChangeListener="#{BeanTest.selectChangeHandler}" required="true" >
           <f:selectItems value="#{ToolsKPI.getMyListKPI()}" />
             </h:selectOneMenu>

<p:panel header="KPI" style="margin-bottom:10px;width:450px;height:350px;" rendered="#{BeanTest.showPanelBoolClosed}" >
<h1>KPI1</h1>
<br></br> 
test <h:inputText autocomplete="on"  value="#{BeanTest.test}" />
<h:commandButton immediate="true"  action="#{BeanTools.testt}"  value="Valid" />

</p:panel>



                <p:panel rendered="#{BeanTest.showPanelBoolOpen}" >

                    <br></br>
                    <h1>KPI2</h1>
             <h:inputText value="test2" />
             <h:inputText value="test3" />
  </h:form>
```

**Navigation rules:**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>ChooseKPI.xhtml</from-view-id>
            <navigation-case>
       <from-action>#{BeanTools.testt}</from-action>
       <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
       <to-view-id>Test1.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
       <from-action>#{BeanTools.testt}</from-action>
       <from-outcome>false</from-outcome>
       <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
```

```
Managed Bean:

public boolean testt()
{   
 if(test.equals("a"))

    return true;
else 
    return false;

}
```

Should I add another form? If yes how can I mention the second form in the navigation rule?

Thank you

Comment: @Wade thank you for the reply , I have add this method just to test the functionality of the button,this methode work fine .

Comment: which scope your managedbean is?

Comment: @madhu ,the scope of the managedbean is request

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using conditional navigation instead:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/conditional-navigation-rule-in-jsf-2-0/

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>start.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>test</from-outcome>
        <if>#{BeanTools.testt}</if>
        <to-view-id>finish.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I'm not sure if you can use boolean types with from-outcome...I've only ever used/seen Strings.

Comment: @DD ,thank you for the reply I will try the conditional navigation and yes you can use boolean types with from-outcome I have used them before.